# How to model notched detail on a gun?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I am modeling an MTAR familiar and I have to create certain part of the gun which is quite complex. I am not sure what would be the best way of doing it, I was thinking to do it with and Array modifier and then somehow join it, or maybe by adding a lot of loop cuts.

[image: reference image]

**So I would like to know how one would Approach this task?**

Comment: It's really not as difficult as it would seem, just add edges code to one another to make it more detailed

Comment: You might want to specify if you want a high quality reproduction for distance shots or super high quality reproduction with close up views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this I would first add some loop cuts along your object where you want the extrusions, **one** loop cut for each extrusion.  Then, with the loop cuts selected, bevel them with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.  You can then select the proper up-facing faces and extrude them to your liking.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Loop Cut.

Select every other loop and slide into position for the spacing you want.

Array modifier might be an alternative.

Create vertex group if you like.

Extrude individual faces. 
Shape Ends.

Comment: You should probably post a bit more info here

Comment: Feel free to edit the post.  I do not get the impression the original post needs a tutorial.

Comment: Remember that this site is not only for the person who started the question but for anyone who might come across this question. They might not be so knowledgeable and able to interpret your suggestions.